# Get date of last earnings announcement for a stock

Tags: pine-script, stock

How can I get the date of the last earnings announcement for a stock in TradingView?

I am using pinescript v5

Comment: Do found how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use earnings.actual and specify the stock, as shown for Microsoft:

```
earnings_actual = earnings("NASDAQ:MSFT", earnings.actual)
earnings_estimate = earnings("NASDAQ:MSFT", earnings.estimate)
```

The date should be returned in the `Date` parameter. If this is not suitable for your use case, please add more context.